Trying to iterate over different teams in mean data from a larger dataset
Basically after the mean data for the teams home and away games is taken, I want to plot multiple graphs for each team in one loop, essentially, in the code below, where Arsenal is in quotes in the first meangoal_df variable I just want to iterate each team in that spot and plot a graph for each one, there's an attatched picture of what the graph should look like.
    `Homearray = matches_df['HomeTeam'].unique()
    x = len(Homearray)

    meanData = {}

    for team in Homearray:
    season1 = matches_df.loc[(matches_df["Game"] >= 0) & (matches_df["Game"] <= 379) &                (matches_df['HomeTeam'] == team), ["FTHG", "FTAG"]].mean()
    season2 = matches_df.loc[(matches_df["Game"] >= 380) & (matches_df["Game"] <= 759)& (matches_df['HomeTeam'] == team), ["FTHG", "FTAG"]].mean()
    season3 = matches_df.loc[(matches_df["Game"] >= 760) & (matches_df["Game"] <= 1139)& (matches_df['HomeTeam'] == team), ["FTHG", "FTAG"]].mean()
    season4 = matches_df.loc[(matches_df["Game"] >= 1140) & (matches_df["Game"] <= 1519)& (matches_df['HomeTeam'] == team), ["FTHG", "FTAG"]].mean()
    season5 = matches_df.loc[(matches_df["Game"] >= 1520) & (matches_df["Game"] <= 1899)& (matches_df['HomeTeam'] == team), ["FTHG", "FTAG"]].mean()
    season6 = matches_df.loc[(matches_df["Game"] >= 1900) & (matches_df["Game"] <= 2279)& (matches_df['HomeTeam'] == team), ["FTHG", "FTAG"]].mean()
    season7 = matches_df.loc[(matches_df["Game"] >= 2280) & (matches_df["Game"] <= 2659)& (matches_df['HomeTeam'] == team), ["FTHG", "FTAG"]].mean()
    season8 = matches_df.loc[(matches_df["Game"] >= 2660) & (matches_df["Game"] <= 3039)& (matches_df['HomeTeam'] == team), ["FTHG", "FTAG"]].mean()
    season9 = matches_df.loc[(matches_df["Game"] >= 3040) & (matches_df["Game"] <= 3419)& (matches_df['HomeTeam'] == team), ["FTHG", "FTAG"]].mean()
    season10 = matches_df.loc[(matches_df["Game"] >= 3419) & (matches_df["Game"] <= 3799)& (matches_df['HomeTeam'] == team), ["FTHG", "FTAG"]].mean()
    season11 = matches_df.loc[(matches_df["Game"] >= 3420) & (matches_df["Game"] <= 4179)& (matches_df['HomeTeam'] == team), ["FTHG", "FTAG"]].mean()
    season12 = matches_df.loc[(matches_df["Game"] >= 4180) & (matches_df["Game"] <= 4559)& (matches_df['HomeTeam'] == team), ["FTHG", "FTAG"]].mean()
    season13 = matches_df.loc[(matches_df["Game"] >= 4560) & (matches_df["Game"] <= 4939)& (matches_df['HomeTeam'] == team), ["FTHG", "FTAG"]].mean()
    season14 = matches_df.loc[(matches_df["Game"] >= 4940) & (matches_df["Game"] <= 5319)& (matches_df['HomeTeam'] == team), ["FTHG", "FTAG"]].mean()
    season15 = matches_df.loc[(matches_df["Game"] >= 5320) & (matches_df["Game"] <= 5699)& (matches_df['HomeTeam'] == team), ["FTHG", "FTAG"]].mean()
    season16 = matches_df.loc[(matches_df["Game"] >= 5670) & (matches_df["Game"] <= 6079)& (matches_df['HomeTeam'] == team), ["FTHG", "FTAG"]].mean()
    season17 = matches_df.loc[(matches_df["Game"] >= 6080) & (matches_df["Game"] <= 6459)& (matches_df['HomeTeam'] == team), ["FTHG", "FTAG"]].mean()
    season18 = matches_df.loc[(matches_df["Game"] >= 6460) & (matches_df["Game"] <= 6839)& (matches_df['HomeTeam'] == team), ["FTHG", "FTAG"]].mean()
    meanData[team] = [season1, season2,season3,season4,season5,season6,season7,season8,season9,season10,season11,season12,season13,season14,season15,season16,season17,season18]


    
    meangoal_df = pd.DataFrame(data = meanData['Arsenal'])
    meangoal_df2 = meangoal_df.assign(Year=yearArr)

    fthgPlot = sns.regplot(data = meangoal_df2, x = 'Year',y='FTHG',label = 'Full Time Home Goal')
    ftagPlot = sns.regplot(data = meangoal_df2, x = 'Year',y='FTAG', ax=fthgPlot, label = 'Full Time Away Goal')

    fthgPlot.set(xlabel = 'Year' , ylabel = 'Mean full time goals')
    plt.legend()`

I tried googling this before and I got this answer:
    `import seaborn as sns

    for i in range(4):
        subset = data[data['column'] == i]
        sns.lineplot(x='x', y='y', data=subset, label=f'Graph {i}')

    plt.title('Multiple Graphs')
    plt.xlabel('X-axis label')
    plt.ylabel('Y-axis label')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()`

Obviously with our own plots replaced but because the mean data is what we want to plot but its wants to pull from the original dataset where it only has HomeTeam and AwayTeam as columns when both should be plotted so just team doesn't exist and HomeTeam and AwayTeam aren't defined in the code, even though we don't want to define them.

1- please provide a [mre], i.e. the minimal and sufficient code that will allow us to reproduce your issue. Craft a dummy dataset if needed and remove everything that is not relevant. 2- don't use loops in pandas, you can take advantage of cut to bin a column.
